# how to implement scrolling in ionic mobile application framework

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-slide-box>
       <ion-slide>
           <ion-item collection-repeat="item in result" type="item-text-wrap"></ion-item>
       </ion-slide>
       <ion-slide>
           <ion-item collection-repeat="item in result" type="item-text-wrap"></ion-item>           
       </ion-slide> 
</ion-content>
```

how do I implement ion-infinite scroll for each ion-item because each ion-items are on separate tabs.

Comment: your code is not visible. Please check that so that we can understand your actual problem.

Comment: 404 code not found